# Create summary string of row contents by group using dplyr

Tags: r, string, dplyr, concatenation, summary

I'm doing a `group_by` + `summarize()` operation on a large dataframe for a lot of groups and across a lot of rows. On the aggregated dataset (each line a group), I would like to concatenate all the row entries in one string per line.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~country, ~var,     
  "France", "Apple",  
  "France", "Pear",   
  "France", "Orange", 
  "France", "Apple",  
  "USA", "Pear",   
  "USA", "Pear",   
  "USA", "Orange" 
)
```

The output that should result is:

```
df_summarized <- tribble(
   ~country, ~summary,
  "France", "Apple, Pear, Orange, Apple", 
  "USA", "Pear, Pear, Orange"
)
```

Comment: How about `df %>% group_by(country) %>% summarise(summary = paste(var,collapse = ", "))`?

Comment: Wow, didn't think it would be that easy - thanks! Should I withdraw the question?

Comment: I closed it for you as a duplicate. It can act as a signpost if you want.